# Extracting data from protocol read

Tags: c++, character-encoding, binary, int

Let's assume my protocol defines a message lenght (without overhead) of 40 Bytes.
There are 20 variables/information included, with different lenght.

While reading the message, I create the `messageContent[byteNumber]` of each read Byte.

If I want to save, say the first of those 20 variables that is `284`in decimal, it would be 
`0001 0001 1100` in binary. But that is one and a half Byte, and only full Bytes are transmitted. So I would recive `0001 0001     0000 1100`?

That would mean that `messageContent[0] = 0001 0001` 
and `messageContent[1] = 0000 1100`.

Then I want to declare my variable `value01`:

`uint32_t value01= messageContent[0] + messageContent[1]`.

I have 5 questions to this subject:

1. As a 32 Bit int, it should look like `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0001 1100`, right?
2. So my definition of `value01` is wrong, because it would somehow try to sum up three binary numbers. How to get around this? I need to tell the program, that the first `0001 0001` is not a 17, but a 272 (=17+255). The second byte would then be the missing 12, so `1100`.
3. How are those bytes treated internally? How does the program know, that it is for example 1110 in binary and not 1110 in decimal?
4. If I save the `value01` on a SD-card with `cout << value01`, how much is the file on the card getting bigger? 32 Bit = 4 Bytes?
5. If I know that one value of those 40 Byte-message won't exceed the value of 15, could I use the type `uint8_t` instead of `uint32_t`and save space on the card? In the end after decades of values, there is only one CSV-file.

Thanks for taking the time to read this stuff.

Comment: Please see:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness.  If you're going to be doing this kind of stuff, you *have* to know about endianness first.

Comment: Do you refer to the `284 = 0001 0001 0000 1100`? So it should be `0000 0001 0001 1100`?

Comment: It's going to be either `0000 0001 0001 1100` **or** `1100 0001 0001 0000` depending on the endianness of the hardware.

Comment: You can discover the endianness you are working with by using code like 
`
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
typedef unsigned char byte;
bool testEndianness()
{
    byte test[2]= { 1, 0 };
 if( *(short *) test== 1 ) {return true;}
 else { return false;}
}

int main()
{
   cout << "Hello World, Am I little endian?" << testEndianness()<< endl; 
   
   return 0;
}
`

That's a trick from games programming :)  let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Ok let's say my endianess is correct, what about my other questions? Are my assumptions okay?